# No member named 'cancelButtonTintColor' in 'JS::NativeActionSheetManager::SpecShowActionSheetWithOptionsOptions'

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, version, xcodebuild

**Description**

How to fix this error. I have created simple project with latest version and when try to build the project via `Xcode` it generate error?

**Version**

0.67.3

**`Output of` npx `react-native info`**

```
OS: macOS 11.5.2
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 83.30 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 14.18.2 - /usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.15 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.14.15 - /usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/npm
Watchman: Not Found
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922
Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 15.0.2 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.67.3 => 0.67.3
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native: Not Found
```

**Steps to reproduce**

Please `init` new react native project with command and try to build the project in the `xcode` after pod install

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could create that into the library source or you could avoid it and use the same UIColor option just above it.

**I removed:**
( *[RCTConvert UIColor:options.cancelButtonTintColor() ? @(* options.cancelButtonTintColor()) : nil];* )
**and replace it with:**
( *[RCTConvert UIColor:options.tintColor() ? @(*options.tintColor()) : nil]*; )

my line now looks like:

```
UIColor *cancelButtonTintColor =
[RCTConvert UIColor:options.tintColor() ? @(*options.tintColor()) : nil];
```

it is not the better way, but you can do it in the meanwhile this is fixed.

Comment: don't do it. every time you install new module, you have edit it again. just "command + shift + k" => rebuild, that work.

Comment: This is worked for me on RN 67.5 but i need to do it every build

Answer (score 40):

after each time pod-install => clean build XCode > Product > Clean Build Folder(command + shift + k) => rebuild, that work.
The problem is with rn > 0.67.0, pod-cache pointing to the old file.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/01856633a1d42ed3b26e7cc93a007d7948e1f76e

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What he said is to clean the build folder on XCode > Product > Clean Build Folder. This worked for me.

Comment: this answer worked thanks!

Answer (score 2):

clean build folder after pod install worked for me

in top navigation bar click on Production ---> Clean Build Folder